# Is it possible to stop the garbage collector OR to force it to run at specific time?

Tags: java, android, performance, garbage-collection

On Android, is there any way to stop the garbage collector for some time? I need this because I have some lags in my animation. If their is no way, can I force the garbage collector to run at some specific time (for example when my animation is pausing) ?

Comment: No, Oreo is future.

Comment: No. you can 'request' the GC to run, but the GC will 'decide' on it's own whether or not to comply. calling GC.run does not guarantee it also will.

Comment: You really think garbage collector is reason for laggy animation?

Comment: Every apps without laggy animation have to use default gc behave too.

Comment: @tilz0R i not sure but i would like to remove this hypothese from the table ;)

Comment: @loki, I would says you have a problem with your coding (architecture) approach. Garbage collector in low-level thing, which does not influence you code almost nothing.

Comment: You can be sure that this isn't related to garbage collection. You should inspect your code for possible issues or - if you don't see any - ask here what could cause the lagging (with the relevant code included).

Comment: at least is their anyway to know when the garbage collector is done (and i can see if my lags is because of the garbage collector) ? i m not an android studio, i m building a native app with Delphi

Comment: also from https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html : "As you allocate more objects in your app, you will force a periodic garbage collection, creating little "hiccups" in the user experience."

Comment: to everyone, i just did the test and i have now absolutely no doubt that the lag i saw in my animation are caused by GC or something similare

Comment: *or something similar* ... so you don't actually know whether it was the GC.